# Using AJAX to pass value from range slider to PHP on front-page of wordpress site

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, wordpress

So I have a range slider in the footer of my whole site:

```
<input id="ex1" type="range" min="0" max="60" step="1" />

<div id='mydiv'>test</div>
```

And on slideStop I am redirecting to my homepage:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#ex1').on('change', function () {

if (document.location.href.indexOf('category') > -1)
    { 
window.location.href = 'http://localhost/wordpress/'; 
 }

var id = $(this).val();

$.ajax({
type: "post",
dataType: "json",
url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", 
data: {
    action:'get_data', 
    id: id
},

success:function(data) {
$('#mydiv').html(data);
}

});
});

});
```

And I want to pass the value of my range slider into the php on my wordpress front-page. This is the code:

```
<?php

$query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag' => ' ***INSERT RANGE SLIDER VALUE HERE*** ' ) );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :

while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();?>

    <?php the_content();?>

<?php endwhile; endif;?>
```

So if the range slider stops on 44, the home page would show all posts tagged '44'.

I haven't used AJAX before and struggling to understand where to get started.

Thanks !

Comment: The problem lies with you redirecting to your home page. You'd have to pass a variable in the home page url to be actioned upon or update a table and put some code on the home page to check that table data.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way would be to pass your var ass url parameter. On your front-page, just read this parameter and set is as parameter for your query. You just have to change some parts in your files.

change your js at this part:

```
window.location.href = "http://localhost/wordpress?slider=12";
```

No magic here, just add any parameter to your url, in this example: 12.

---

In your php-file:

```
$slider   = $_GET['slider'];
$query    = new WP_Query( array( 'tag' => $slider ) );
```

Just us a GET-Request for your url - parameter (in this example we use "slider" ).

Any questions?

Answer (score 2):

Try with this code -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ex1").change(function() {  
    var field = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      url:"ajax-action-file.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:{value:field},
      success:function(data) {
        $('#Response-Div').html(data);
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey, I have just edited the question to the most recent code I am trying, I have it working with the code above, thanks ! How would you suggest recalling the value into my php on the home page?

Answer (score 1):

This will output the current value of the slider after user interaction to a div.

**HTML**

```
 <input id='ex1' type='range' min='0' max='60' step='1'>
 <div id='mydiv'></div>
```

**JS (jQuery 3.4.1)**

```
 $("#ex1").change(function() {  
 var id = $('#ex1').val();
 $.ajax({
 url:"myserverfile.php",
 method:"POST",
 data:{id:id},
 dataType:"text",
 success:function(data) {
 $('#mydiv').html(data);
 }
 });
 });
```

- I have tested this code.
- I didn't include any PHP here as all mine did is echo back the value of the slider through the POST index of ['id'] but it proves communcation is working through AJAX.
- Check my comment for how to handle things after home page redirect.

Comment: Hey, am struggling to get this to work, have made some edits (below), but still not working. Should I be making something in my functions.php file ? Or enqueing my admin-ajax.php file? Or it should be doing this automatically?

$(document).ready(function(){

//!

$('#ex1').on('change', function () {

 var id = $(this).val();

 $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    data: {id:id},

 success:function(data) {
 $('.card-deck').html(data);
 }

 });
 });

//!

});

Comment: Have posted a new question with more details !
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64031254/problems-using-ajax-to-pass-a-value-from-a-range-slider-in-footer-to-front-page

Comment: @joehigh All that was in my PHP was echo $_POST['id']; as id was the data being posted to the PHP file. What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I'm using 3.5.1. So in my functions I now have the following, but it isn't working still :
function head_script(){?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var ajaxurl = "<?php echo $_POST['id'];?>";
        </script>

    <?php }
add_action( 'wp_head', 'head_script' 
);

Comment: There's been some security updates from 3.4.1 (the code I wrote) to 3.5.1 so this part - $('#mydiv').html(data); - won't work, specifically just the .html part is affected. I haven't yet upgraded so I don't know what the work around is but this is def. the problem.

Comment: But I was using $('.card-deck').html($(this).val() + "<br/>"); before, and this was functioning?

Comment: Yes, what you wrote above which grabs the value of a div works but what I mentioned, changing/injecting HTML content into a div doesn't in 3.5.1 - I've tried it.

Comment: It's working ! Just uploaded my code to live site, and is working, for some reason wasn't working on my local version. How would u recommend adding the data / value into my php code on front-page ? (In the code above: $query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag' => ' ***INSERT RANGE SLIDER VALUE HERE*** ' ) ); )

Comment: Good to know it's working. I'm not familiar with Wordpress but I'm sure you could find the answer by googling. There's lots of videos on Wordpress on YT.